# MatLab - Modify Tic Toc Return Value

Tags: matlab, timer

I am using the `tic` and `toc` within MatLab which is returning a double of hrs, mins, secs, etc.  Is there a way to force the return value so it returns milliseconds in the form of an long unsigned integer?

One of my variables starts defined as an integer `diff1 = int32(0)`, but when I do a calculation on two other variables that store the return value from `tic` and `toc`, `diff1` gets converted back to a double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the conversion manually:

```
uint32(floor(toc*1000)); %// or "round" instead of "floor"
```

Example

```
>> tic, randn(1000); t = uint32(floor(toc*1000))
t =
          49

>> whos t
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  t         1x1                 4  uint32
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be doing the trick. Will I be loosing any precision?

Comment: Well, you get a precision of milliseconds. `toc` gives more precision than that, but you lose it in the rounding operation